# How to add colors to barh based on the value range?

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I'm trying to add colors to a matplotlib barh graph based on the criteria that certain ranges or name type get an assigned color. Its kind of grouping similar data with the same color. Even though they occur at different instances. Here's a snippet of the code which always produces all black barh.

```
begin_dates = []
end_dates = []
job_names = []
job_colors = {}
color_list = []
color_counter = 0
for each in jobs:
    begin_dates.append(each.start_time)
    end_dates.append(each.end_time)
    name = each.job_name.split('(')[0]
    job_names.append(name)
    if name not in job_colors.keys():
        job_colors[name] = color_counter
        color_counter += 1
    color_list.append(job_colors[name])
end_dates, begin_dates = [mdates.date2num(item) for item in (end_dates, begin_dates)]
ypos = range(len(end_dates))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(ypos,end_dates-begin_dates,left=begin_dates,align='center',color = color_list)
ax.axis('tight')
ax.xaxis_date()
#in case you want to display the names uncomment the bottom line.
#plt.yticks(range(len(job_names)),job_names,size='small')
plt.show()
```

Appreciate your help.Thanks!

Comment: Please post the content of your data for a minimal testing example. I'm not able to run your code as it is.

Comment: Oh I finally found the problem. addding edgecolor='none' makes the colors appear. Thanks for the help anyways :)